# Как выбрать все option в select multiple на angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, html-select

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="item_value" multiple>
  <option value='{{level_1}}' ng-if='valid(level_1)' ng-repeat="level_1 in level_1_list">{{level_1.name_level_1}}</option>
</select>
```

Нужно сделать так что бы первоначально были выбраны все возможные `option`.
Как это сделать? Если я поставлю просто `selected`, ангуляру будет поровну.

Comment: [ng-selected="expression"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick так не работает <select  
ng-selected="expression" class="form-control"  ng-model="item_value" multiple>
  <option value='{{level_1}}' ng-if='valid(level_1)' ng-repeat="level_1 in level_1_list">{{level_1.name_level_1}}</option>
</select> и так не работает <select  
 class="form-control"  ng-model="item_value" multiple>
  <option ng-selected="expression" value='{{level_1}}' ng-if='valid(level_1)' ng-repeat="level_1 in level_1_list">{{level_1.name_level_1}}</option>
</select>

Comment: при каком условии option должен быть выбран?

Comment: опиши, пожалуйста, что тебе надо более детальнее: при каком условии должен быть выбран option, может ты по статусу в level_1  как то проверяешь.

Comment: "выбраны все возможные option" не совсем понятно что ты имеешь ввиду. Ты же не можешь сделать   selected больше 1 option.

Comment: Если тебе надо несколько option сделать selected то должен использовать атрибут [multiple](http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/selected)

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick я указал multiple, и хочу что бы по умолчанию были выбраны все option которые есть.

Comment: вместо ng-repeat лучше использовать ng-options. Выбранные элементы соответствуют значению в ng-model. Если надо выбрать все - присвой в ng-model массив со всеми элементами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с `ng-selected` вариант:

```js
angular.module('staticSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.item_value = null;
   $scope.level_1_list = [
      {name_level_1: 'test', id:1},
      {name_level_1: 'test2',  id:2 },
      {name_level_1: 'test3',  id:3 },
   ];
   
   $scope.valid = function (data) {
      return true;
   }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="staticSelect" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <select class="form-control"  ng-model="item_value" multiple>
    <option value='{{level_1}}' ng-if='valid(level_1)' ng-selected="true" ng-repeat="level_1 in level_1_list">{{level_1.name_level_1}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Вариант с ng-options (по совету  Grundy):

```js
angular.module('staticSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   
   $scope.level_1_list = [
      {name_level_1: 'test', id:1},
      {name_level_1: 'test2',  id:2 },
      {name_level_1: 'test3',  id:3 },
   ];
   
  function valid () {
       return $scope.level_1_list.filter(function (item) {
          return item.id != 1;
      })
  };
  
  $scope.selectedLevels = $scope.allArr = valid();
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="staticSelect" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <select class="form-control" 
        data-ng-model="selectedLevels" 
       data-ng-options="item.name_level_1 for item in allArr" 
       multiple>
   
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно с версией 1.6.0  не работает... Поменял версию на вашу и все заработало...

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко а у Вас безболезнено прошёл переход на 1.2.23 ?

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко а вы не пробовали, как  Grundy советует, с  ng-options вместо ng-repeat?

Comment: 1. Последствий перехода не обнаружил. 2. Как Grundy советовал пробовал, успеха не было, 3. Ваше решения действительно выделяет все option, вот только жаль в модели не появляются(item_value)=( Это я прочекал даже как отдельный код вне моего приложения

Comment: Кстати как Grundy  советует, не работает ваше решение не как

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко обновил пример

Comment: тут нету проверки(valid) =))) я почти добрался до еще одного решенияXD Но блин, это не круто, все решения через одно место

Comment: обновил пример.

Comment: теперь валидация в контроллере. Вам надовставить свою функцию валидации

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, можно было в разметке filter сразу использовать

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко, _как Grundy советует, не работает ваше решение не как_ - что именно не работает?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, что-то у тебя второе решение странное: и в ng-model, и в ng-options стоит одно и тот же выражение - ты ведь когда изменишь ng-model - у тебя список options изменится в этом случае

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, что заметили, поправил

Comment: @Grundy я невнимательно прочитал ваш комментарий. Да, в итоге это боле менее адекватное решение в итоге. Мой рабочий вариант в проекте  с ng-options. Но мое личное мнение что это все танцы с бубнами. Жаль что нету возможности сделать это проще.

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко, ng-options как раз стандартное решение для селектов. Что именно проще должно быть?

Comment: @Grundy например возможность всем option указывать атрибуты. Вот с какого я не могу через ng-options указывать атрибуты!?

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко, например потому, что ты не должен исходить из разметки. У тебя все должно от данных исходить. Все _нужные_ атрибуты и так выставляются. какие тебе нужные еще атрибуты кроме текста и значения в option?